# Why does the file not upload? PHP and FTP

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to upload a variable into a json file on my server
todo so I use PHP to make connection and login to the FTP server.
This is the code I use:

```
<?php
    $ftp_server = $_POST["ftp_server"];
    $database_url = $_POST["database_url"];
    $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
    $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]);

    $file = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
    fwrite($file, $_POST["pass_json"]);

    if (ftp_nb_put($ftp_conn, $database_url, $file, FTP_ASCII)){
      echo "Successfully uploaded $file.";
    } else {
      echo "Failed to upload $file.";
    }
    rewind($file);
    ftp_close($ftp_conn);
?>
```

The connection is valid (`$ftp_conn`). the login is valid as well (`$login`).

`$_POST["pass_json"]` is the correct information and `$_POST["database_url"]` is the url you fill in your webbrowser to look at the json file in your webbrowser.
this is being done with a SSL certificate in https to protect the username and password given. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just wondering dont you have to close the file first before uploading?

Comment: Now you came up with I should but, when I tried just now again while it's been closed it still fails to upload. `fclose($file)`